# How can I change the colors for my source code on GitHub?

Tags: perl, github, gist

I tried using GitHub to host a gist of Perl code, but I don't think there is enough contrast in colors. Can I modify them? I've tried searching Google, GitHub, and Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this through Github; however, you could always use something like the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on for Firefox to change Github's css locally.\

Since this only changes the css locally, you will see the different style but everyone else who visits your project will still see the standard Github style.